# incapsula proxy appear on my network

Tags: proxy

I was trying to find my ip number as usual on this website 
`https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address`
but I found a second ip on proxy by incapsula
`IP Address 177.250.123.74 [Hide this IP with VPN] 
IP Location Tacuati, San Pedro (PY)  [Details]
Host Name   host-74.123.250.177.copaco.com.py
Proxy   177.250.123.74, 198.143.56.17
Device Type Linux
OS  Ubuntu
Browser Chrome
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/62.0.3202.89 Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
Screen Size 1366px X 768px
Cookie  Enabled
Javascript  Enabled`

no mater how I change my internet connection always is there this ip, on all my computers on my network, what this mean??

why thereis a proxy here on my network? even with vpn, appears the incapsula ip addr.

What kind of information do you guys need to help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple whois on [www.iplocation.net](http://www.iplocation.net) reveals this hostname to be an alias of b7rql.x.incapdns.net.  Evidently, Incapsula is a CDN used by iplocation.net:

Canonical name  b7rql.x.incapdns.net.
Aliases [www.iplocation.net](http://www.iplocation.net)
Addresses   107.154.108.114

b7rql.x.incapdns.net belongs to Impervia, which is in fact another name used by Incapsula.
Their CDN is making the iplocation.net test result unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The "proxy" IP address 198.143.56.17 is not on your network: it does not have even the same prefix as yours.

I used the logger feature in the uBlock Origin browser extension to see what requests are made when accessing that page on www.iplocation.net. While doing this, the page showed me two IP addresses as "proxies": my own IP address, and another incapsula.com address. This makes me think the proxy detection at www.iplocation.net is not currently entirely reliable.

It appears the page includes some references to "incapsula.evyy.net". Looks like this evyy.net is acting as a reverse proxy for Incapsula, and the address finder page detects this and lists it in the "proxy" section. In other words, it is a side effect of www.iplocation.net's own structure.

I also note that this page seems to include some advertising for VPNs. Although the odd "proxy" reporting may be a honest mistake, the fact that they don't explain their "proxy" results in any further detail makes me think it might possibly be deliberate to make the readers worry about their security... and perhaps then buy a VPN.